# changing host.. data loss

Tags: menus

I changed my host from dreamhost to godaddy..

My menubar setup is not showing up.. all of the pages are visible when there is only supposed to be a couple visible .. the site is first in english but you have the option to change it to french and now all the french manu bars are displaying aswell as the english ones ..

also i lost all of my sidebar data .. the custom sidebars/footers i created are showing up in the appearance: widgets section but the content is lost they are all empty !

please help ive been trying to fix all of this for 4days now with barely any seep in between and been on the phone with godaddy but they are clueless :(

thank you

Comment: Do you have access to the database-- PHPMyadmin, something like that ?

Comment: You need to [debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and [troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list). Unfortunately, as it is, this Question seems to be *off-topic* and/or *too-localized*, please read this site [faq]. :::: Oh, sure, related to s_ha_dum above, hopefully you have database backups, no?

Answer (score 2):

When you migrated the site, you probably failed to sufficiently change the paths in the wp-options table.  Dreamhost paths are /home/yourusername/yourdomain.com/ and I would assume GoDaddy paths are something different.

When migrating a WordPress site from one host to another, a search and replace in the database is still needed even if the domain name doesn't change.  The values in question are probably serialized so it is strongly recommended that you [use this script](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) after the initial migration and look for paths that need changing.